# nested web scraping with beautifulSoup

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am looking to download the "Latest File" from provided url below

```
https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/economy/national-accounts/australian-national-accounts-national-income-expenditure-and-product
```

The file i want to download is at the following exact location

```
https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/economy/national-accounts/australian-national-accounts-national-income-expenditure-and-product/sep-2022#data-downloads
```

for example file name is "Table 1"
how can i download this when i am only given the base URL as above? using beautifulSoup

I am unable to figure out how to work through nested urls within the html page to find the one i need to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First u need to get latest link:

```
latest_link = 'https://www.abs.gov.au/' + soup.find('span', class_='flag_latest').find_previous('a').get('href')
```

Then find document to download, in my example - download all, but u can change it:

```
download_all_link = 'https://www.abs.gov.au/' + soup.find('div', class_='anchor-button-wrapper').find('a').get('href')
```

And last point - download it.

FULL CODE:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/economy/national-accounts/australian-national-accounts-national-income-expenditure-and-product'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
latest_link = 'https://www.abs.gov.au/' + soup.find('span', class_='flag_latest').find_previous('a').get('href')
response = requests.get(latest_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
download_all_link = 'https://www.abs.gov.au/' + soup.find('div', class_='anchor-button-wrapper').find('a').get('href')
file_data = requests.get(download_all_link).content
with open(download_all_link.split("/")[-1], 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(file_data)
```

Comment: I need to also get the name of the file from the web and append to the link to create the full download link. so Loop through all files and create download links for all of those .

Answer (score 0):

I've never used BeautifulSoup before. Pretty cool stuff. This seems to do it or me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("demo.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html.parser")

# lets look for the span with the 'flag_latest' class attribute
for span in soup.find_all('span'):
    if span.get('class', None) and 'flag_latest' in span['class']:
        # step up the a level to the div and grab the a tag
        print(span.parent.a['href'])
```

So we just look for the span with the 'flag_latest' class and then step up a level in the tree (a div) and then grab the first a tag and extract the href.

Check out the [docs](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#navigating-the-tree) and read the sections on "Navigating the Tree" and "Searching the Tree"

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. The data i need to download is from the below link https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/economy/national-accounts/australian-national-accounts-national-income-expenditure-and-product/sep-2022/5206001_Key_Aggregates.xlsx. But i only have the base url link as given above. The file name in this link changes every month or quarter. So need to scrape the base url and extract the latest month data

Comment: My demo.html was a dump of that page. The latest document link is followed by a span with the class 'flag_latest'. Here is the output from my code above: `/statistics/economy/national-accounts/australian-national-accounts-national-income-expenditure-and-product/sep-2022` that should be what you need to build the direct file URL. What am I missing?